# How docker deamon retry to make docker container up?

Tags: docker, devops, docker-machine, docker-registry

If the docker container is failing and I want that docker deamon should retry it at least 3 times without giving manual docker run command this to us without manual intervention what I should do ?

Answer (score 0):

Make use of docker's restart policy.
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#restart-policies---restart

If finding out whether a container is up or not is a bit more complex than just noticing that the process has exited, use docker's healthcheck.
https://scoutapm.com/blog/how-to-use-docker-healthcheck